# Prepared statement executeUpdate is not working with update statement

Tags: java, postgresql

Im using the following code to change password using update query of postgres.

```
@POST
@Path("/changepassword")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String changePassword(String msg) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(msg);
    String songString = null;
    String query = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        if (UserManagement.authMail(jsonObject.getString("mail"))) {
            songString = Utilities.constructJSON("welcome", true);

            Connection connection = MyResource.getConnection();
            query = "UPDATE users SET password = '" + jsonObject.getString("password") + "' WHERE mail = ' "
                    + jsonObject.getString("mail") + "'";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            songString = Utilities.constructJSON("Password reset successfull", true);

        } else {
            songString = Utilities.constructJSON("Please check your mail address", true);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        songString = Utilities.constructJSON("" + query + ex, true);
    }
    return songString;
}
```

It is not effecting the database. why is that so? my connection is in auto commit mode but still it is not updating. How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
Connection connection = MyResource.getConnection();
query = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE mail = ?";

stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1,jsonObject.getString("password"));
stmt.setString(2,jsonObject.getString("mail"));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

And Also be sure `jsonObject.getString("password")` and `jsonObject.getString("mail")` is getting some value.

Comment: It's not very helpful to say "you should try this", without explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

The query contains an additional whitespace at the mail parameter, this could result in the query not returning any rows.

```
UPDATE users SET password = 'Password' WHERE mail = ' mailadress'
```

Try removing the whitespace and see if this affects the database.

Also it is preferable to use a prepared statement as mentioned in the answer provided by [Keval Pithva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735689/keval-pithva)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the connection just make :

```
con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

This will help you.

Comment: After ps.executeUpdate() I've added con.commit() and finally my UPDATE query was applied in db.